# Displaying data-message in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').val($('textarea').data('message'));
});
```

```css
.testtextarea {
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Test Page</h2>
  <textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Hello World"></textarea>
  <textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Test Text Area"></textarea>
  <textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Hello Universe"></textarea>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Anyone here knows how to fix this issue? the only `data-message` it is showing is the `data-message` for the first one. What I am trying to do here is to make it show its respective data message per `textarea`.

Thanks

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through all textarea and set value accordingly using $(this)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).data('message'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Test Page</h2>
<textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Hello World"></textarea>

<textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Test Text Area"></textarea>

<textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Hello Universe"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can provide a function to the `val()` method which reads the `data` attribute from each textarea. Try this:

```
$('textarea').val(function() {
    return $(this).data('message');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').val(function() {
    return $(this).data('message');
  });
});
```

```css
.testtextarea {
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Test Page</h2>
<textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Hello World"></textarea>
<textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Test Text Area"></textarea>
<textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Hello Universe"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set text in the current element `this` context. You need to iterate and set the value. [`.val(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) or `.each()` can be used

```
$('textarea').val(function(_, val) {
   return $(this).data('message')
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').val(function(_, val) {
    return $(this).data('message')
  });
});
```

```css
.testtextarea {
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Test Page</h2>
  <textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Hello World"></textarea>

  <textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Test Text Area"></textarea>

  <textarea class="testtextarea" data-message="Hello Universe"></textarea>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.testtextarea').val(function () { return $(this).attr('data-message')});
});
```